# Downloading unsigned applications

Tags: macos, gatekeeper

Using MacOS Sierra, I have downloaded an unsigned app from a website.  When I open it, my security settings prevent me from running the app (it is from an unknown developer), but I can open it from the Security panel in Systems Preferences.  All as expected.

However, if I put the same .zip file I downloaded onto a different server, and download it from there, when I try to run it, I get a different dialog about running applications downloaded from the internet, and if I say to open it anyway, it fails, presenting a dialog saying there was an error (but nothing about what *kind* of error), and the option to check the console (which does not present anything obviously useful).

Can anyone explain this behavior, and what (if anything) I can do to prevent these problems when downloading from this second server?

Answer (score 1):

To get around that, all you need to do is *Right Click* and *Open*
 This will now allow you to open up unsigned or 3rd party apps.

Its an automated safety feature within **SIP** *(System Integrity Protection)*

Comment: I don't think you are asking the question I asked; that is just a shortcut for the first scenario.  It does *not* prevent the app from failing to execute in the second scenario.